# Dealing With "0" Values in Datadog

Tags: python, graph, datadog

I am currently building a set of multiple graphs for my personal company using Datadog. I love how it works but there is only one thing I have not been able to sort out. Whenever my data is generated every 5 minutes, there are times where one or multiple values will come in at '0' which is what I want. The problem is Datadog is for some reason not taking these values into account and so until that same value finally comes in with something other than '0' then nothing will show up saying the value was '0' and then it changed to something else. Instead the graph chooses to create a straight line from the last recorded non-zero value straight to the newest non-zero value. I would love to know how I can get Datadog to consider the zeros and graph them.

In addition, if possible, I would also love to know how I could say something like "if this previous value existed and then on the next set of data it does not show up at all (not even as "0") just assign a "0" to it until it once again appears on the data". Of course for this to be looked into I would need the first problem dealt with.

Here is an image of how it is looking right now which is **NOT** how I wanted to look. The **Red** line shows where all the "0" values land, the **Green** boxes show the last recorded non-zero values.

[Example of '0' values not being graph properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lEAH.png)

I have tried looking through most of the documentation of Datadog as well as their posted YouTube videos with no luck. They for some reason do not address this even when it is in front of them when showing examples. I expected to find some info online but there seems to be little resources at the moment. This resulted in me thinking this could be the best place to finally get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Interpolation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/interpolation/). There are a couple of use cases you specified, you may have to experiment with a few of the options depending on what your data looks like.  For example `Fill Zero` satisfies one of them.

[Datadog Graph Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbcLd.png)

Comment: Thank you very much, the Interpolation is what I am looking for and it does work to an extend. Now the  problem is that I would like it to do a different Interpolation fill between points before they go down to 0. For example, the first recorded point is 15, the one 5 mins later is 13 and after 5 more mins is 0. Between the first two points I would like it to fill the spot with an interpolation of the two instead of making it 0 but then once it actually gets to the third point (the 0) then it would show 0 after that until there is a value again.